# What is the complexity of finding a distortion map on a supersingular elliptic curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, isogenies

Let $E$ be a supersingular elliptic curve which is defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $P\in E$. Then there exist a distortion map with respect to $P$. I am looking for an algorithm which finds the map and the complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The paper "Easy Decision-Diffie-Hellman Groups" by S. Galbraith and V. Rotger contains an algorithm to generate a curve together with a distortion map (as pointed out by yyyyyyyy in the comments).

Computing a distortion map on a random super singular elliptic curve is computationally hard. A distortion map is a smooth endomorphism of the curve, and finding such an endomorphism is a well-known problem in cryptography. See, for instance, Problem 1 in [1]. The problem is heuristically equivalent to finding the entire endomorphism ring of the curve.

[1] L. De Feo, D. Kohel, A. Leroux, C. Petit, B. Wesolowski, SQISign: compact post-quantum signatures from quaternions and isogenies, https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1240.pdf

Comment: That algorithm constructs an elliptic curve *together* with a distortion map. The question asks about finding a distortion map for a *given* curve, which is usually much more difficult.